# Not rendering images with the url() property

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tailwind-css

I'm working on a react projects with tailwind. I made a layout where images are contained in div with dimentions of 80px. When I try to set the bg with property `bg-[url(${image})]`. The image is not rendering correctly. This is also strange because if I write explicitly the url in the property and then set it back to use the variable it seems to work with the url i wrote. As soon as I kill the server and restart it again, it doesn't work again. In the console there are not errors and I have no clue of what could be the problem. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: No, It didn't worked but i found a way of using inline styling without tailwind.
`style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}`. From what I understood tailwind can't create utility classes for dynamic values. Thank you anyway